# Referring collectively to the teachers and students at a university

Tags: word-choice

In designing a learning management system for a university, and I would like to define a user role which groups together teachers and students. Is there any word that refers to them collectively?

The only word that I can think of is "participants", in the sense that both teachers and students participate in learning activities.

Luckily, aside from participants, I only have "system administrators" in my system, so there is no notion of e.g. university administration staff.

Comment: University community?

Comment: Or if we are narrowing out non-academic staff, then we can say *the learning community* or *the academic community* at ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an LMS for big corporate last year - we have trainers and students.  For parts of the database where they were not differentiated I just used the term "**user**".  I mainly did that to allow flexibility.  In that if I want to have others that need reporting or whatever but don't belong to admin - I don't have to have to have a new table or role to describe them.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I'm looking at is "stakeholders", since for an LMS, it is the university staff (in my case, teachers) and students whom are the stakeholders.